Identify movie/TV show from car chase scene
I keep remembering this chase scene but cannot recall the film.
It's a fairly recent (probably 2000 or later, possibly a little earlier) movie, the only scene I can remember is the short chase scene from near the end of the film:
I think it's a cop film set in Miami, the bad guys have gotten away and the good guys give chase in a "borrowed" car from the bad guys house, pretty sure it's a roofless Lamborghini.
The scene is brief and mostly shot from a news-helicopter point-of-view.
The news-copter is reporting on a high-speed chase (several police cars chasing a car/truck, completely unrelated) on a two-lane highway (possibly a bridge), when the good guys in the Lambo come speeding through, weaving between the cop cars, almost making them look like they're stationary.
I know there's not much to go on, I'm hoping the news-helicopter will jog someone's memory, I'll add more details if I remember any.
@BrettFromLA's answer did job my memory a little:

Pretty sure the bad guy was a drug/arms dealer.
The bad guy was Asian/Oriental and good at martial arts.
The cop(s) borrowed a white roofless Lambo from his house to give chase.
The helicopter shots aren't just aerial shots, they're done from the POV of a news reporter (complete with TV channel logo).
The chase ended at an air-strip, bad guy fleeing to his private jet?
I've got a feeling that the shortness of the chase might mean it's a TV show and not a movie (which may make it almost impossible to identify).


OK, see if this fits: a chase scene from Transporter 2. Similarities: Protagonist takes a Lambo from bad guy's house and gives chase, comes across an unrelated high-speed chase after a truck and weaves between the cop cars while this is all reported by a news helicopter, and finally catches up to the bad guy as he boards a private jet. Differences: Bad guy doesn't seem Asian and the Lambo is black.

Transporter 2 would be my guess too.  As to 'not Asian': but "good at martial arts" means he's Asian, right?  ;)

That's it! Though it's a black Lambo and he's not a cop!

There's a scene very similar to this from "Bad Boys II", except that there are shots in the car as well as helicopter shots.  Will Smith and Martin Lawrence are in an amazing sports car, driving on a bridge in Florida.  Here's the clip.  (Now that I watch it again, it doesn't have much news-helicopter footage.  It's still a fun scene though!)

As soon as you said "Bad Boys II", I thought, that's it! Unfortunately it's not. It has jogged my memory a little so I'll update the question.
